# How can i assign Mule Variable Value to Property Key -Value lookup?

Tags: groovy, mule

1. I want to find out the careerName from variable
2. I want to use that CareerName as Property Key. Example. If careerName came-up as apple, I have value setup against that key apple=ST\*214|ST\*210.

I have following line of code for Mule Choice Expression, which i tried with but i am not getting success here.

mule-esb.test1.properties

ftp.inbound.carriers.path='CareerName1/InBound/','CareerName2/InBound/','CareerName3/InBound','CareerName4/InBound/','apple/InBound/'

CareerName1=ST\*214|ST\*210

CareerName2=ST\*214|ST\*210

CareerName3=.\*ST.214.\*

CareerName4=ST\*214

apple=ST\*214

```
<context:property-placeholder location="mule-esb.${mule.env}.properties" />

<when expression="import java.util.regex.Pattern;Pattern p = Pattern.compile('${'+message.getInvocationProperty('careerName')+'}');return p.matcher(payload.toString()).find();" evaluator="groovy">
```

Looking for some alternatives or solution on this script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MEL has extensive regex support, you shouldn't need to use Groovy. See: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+Tips#MuleExpressionLanguageTips-RegexSupport

You need to load your properties in an `Map` that you can query from the registry but also use in the property placeholder resolver. So do this:

```
<util:properties id="configProperties"
      location="classpath:mule-esb.${mule.env}.properties" />

<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="configProperties"  />
```

With this in place, the following should work:

```
<when expression="#[regex(app.registry.configProperties[careerName])]">
```

Comment: But how can i combine provide careerName value as Property Key here ? <when expression="#[regex(${#[variable:careerName]})]">

Comment: I don't understand your question: I thought you had a flow var (aka invocation property) named `careerName`. Isn't that the case?

Comment: No i have property file mule-esb.properties which has a property name apple=ST\*214|ST\*210

careerName is a flowVar which will provide me information about careerName as per this example it will return me apple as value. 

#[carrerName]=apple
${apple}

Comment: OK. How do you load the mule-esb.properties file?

Comment: <context:property-placeholder location="mule-esb.${mule.env}.properties" />

Comment: Let me know if i can find any solution on this ?

Comment: I have reviewed my answer.

Comment: thanks for your help, i am half way to the solution. My Regex stopped working with this. please review my answer.

Comment: This line of code <when expression="#[regex(app.registry.configProperties[careerName])]"> instead of returning true/false here, it's returning me null value. This is my regex runtime value - [regex('ST\*214|ST\*210')] which i am trying to search on string payload. Which has "516*X*004010~ST*214*62498~" this payload.

Comment: I also tried to put this code in my flow.                      <set-variable variableName="testsds" value="#[regex(app.registry.configProperties[careerName])]" doc:name="Variable test"/> I can see following message on my local mule studio 
org.mule.transformer.simple.AddFlowVariableTransformer: Variable with key "testsds", not found on message using "#[regex(app.registry.configProperties[careerName])]". Since the value was marked optional, nothing was set on the message for this variable

Comment: I think things work as expected here: `null` is the expected result when the regex doesn't match.

Comment: Yes Null is expected in the case when payload doesn't have that value... But here payload "516*X*004010~ST*214*62498~" has  this "ST*214" value as part of the input.... But it's still returning me Null. My Regex - regex('(ST\\*214|ST\\*210)')

Comment: Thanks a lot David. You made my day today by providing solution around dynamic property value assignment.... I figured out on regex issue i changed my regex with this ^.*(ST\\*214|ST\\*210).*$ and it's working now.....

Answer (score 0):

define a spring bean globally configuring the key value pair properties for the bean.
the bean definition should accept the spring properties and a method which accept the key and returns the corresponding value.

sample bean definition as follows
`<spring:bean id="entityMapper" name="entityMapper" class="com.xx.xx.commons.ClassNameXX">
            <spring:property name="entities">
                <spring:props>
                    <spring:prop key="CareerName1">${CareerName1}</spring:prop>
                    .
                    .
                </spring:props>
            </spring:property>
        </spring:bean>`

so in the flow level you can get value from bean with below expression.
`#[app.registry.entityMapper.getEntity(message.getInvocationProperty('careerName'))]`

where entityMapper will be the bean name and getEntity is the method defined in bean which accept the careerName and return the corresponding value.

hope this helps.
Dynamically you cant access the value directly from context placeholder.

Comment: HI Mohan, I am looking for a solution where i don't need to redeploy the application, mule-esb.properties approach will allow me to put my search criteria in Property File. While using Spring Property approach i still needs to update the code if in future Career related Search criteria going to be changed.  That's why i am leaning towards context property approach rather then having Spring Property approach. I updated my use case information with more details included regarding 2 different properties. One is available as part of Value and Another is as part of Key.